# Visual C# 2008 Control to set a path

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Greetings,

What control in Visual C# 2008 would allow me to set a path and get the value of that path.

For example:
I want the user to click a button then select a path where he/she would do the operation such as save a file in selected path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [FolderBrowserDiaglog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)

```
var folderBrowserDiaglog = new FolderBrowserDiaglog();
if ( folderBrowserDiaglog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
{
  string path = folderBrowserDiaglog.SelectedPath;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to repeat, but none of the other answers seemed to be exactly what you wanted.

There are 3 controls: FolderBrowserDialog, OpenFileDialog, and SaveFileDialog. There names are pretty intuitive. You use all 3 the same way. Tanascius has a good example in his post. The folder dialog you would use if you want the user to select a whole folder to look at. The open you would use if you want the user to select one or many files to open. Save is the same as open, but you would use it when saving a file out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows Forms, try the [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx). All common dialogs descend from [`CommonDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.commondialog.aspx), so looking at the descendents of that class may help, too.

Answer (score 0):

The FolderBrowse Dialog....

Answer (score 0):

SaveFileDialog (for a file) or FolderBrowserDialog (for a folder). Located in the dialogs tab in the toolbox.