# Adding onClick event for a button to get Folder Browser function. VS2010 - Web Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, directory

I have never ever worked with Folder Browsing function.
Basically I would like to get a Folder Browser(like when u upload a file and click browse) as a Button OnClick event.
The only function I need for is to select a location(drive,folder) and save that location into a string.

Any ideas, tutorials ?

Comment: i think the same quesion had been asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663730/visual-c-sharp-2008-control-to-set-a-path

Comment: You can't do that on website. What do you want that for?

Comment: I need to browse a location, and save the location in a string. Later on I will use this location string to several function. Do you have any idea how to browse folder ?

Answer (score 1):

[FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1;

folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

String path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog control for this purpose:

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial67_Using-OpenFileDialog-to-open-files.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From [FolderBrowserDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FOLDERBROWSERDIALOG%29;k%28FOLDERBROWSERDIALOG%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

You can try something like

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(fbd.SelectedPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but nothing happens After I click the button

Comment: Did you attach this event handler to the buttons Click Event? something like button.Click += button_Click;

Comment: I have created the button, then double click that, and in the button private void button_click I used this method. Should I change or add something?

Comment: (It is a Web Site created in VS2010.)

Comment: ASP.Net? Not Winforms? FolderBrowserDialog Class is for WinForms.

Comment: it is an ASP.net Web Site.. sorry for not mentioning earlier, just edited my question . Any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard Folder Browser control available for ASP.Net or I would say HTML. The workaround that I can think of is to create an ActiveX control(IE only) or in Flash or JFileChooser for Java.

There is a File Upload control that will let you browse but it won't allow you to select a folder, only files.

```
<input type="file">
```